# Camel exchange expired via jetty continuation

Tags: jetty, apache-camel

Is there a possibility in Apache Camel to register a handler for managing exchanges that cannot be written to jetty endpoint http response because continuation timeout has been reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. Maybe you need to set a higher timeout if you have some slow processing exchanges.

You are welcome to dive in the Jetty APIs to see if you can find a hook for such a onTimeout event and see what it takes to support that in camel-jetty.

Comment: For now, there is a solution but needs some adjustments. You may have a look at my suggestion below and evaluate if it is a possibility to get it in camel-jetty.

Comment: Thanks that seems like a good solution. I have logged a ticket about this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10175. You are welcome to work on a patch / PR to implement this out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add my notes on that because I made it available in my project by modifying CamelContinuationServlet in the `if (continuation.isExpired())` block like this

```
if (continuation.isExpired()) {
  String id = (String) continuation.getAttribute(EXCHANGE_ATTRIBUTE_ID);
  // remember this id as expired
  expiredExchanges.put(id, id);
  log.warn("Continuation expired of exchangeId: {}", id);

  consumer.getBinding().doWriteExceptionResponse(new TimeoutException(), response);

  return;
}
```

in combination with a custom HttpBinding called `ErrorHandlingHttpBinding` in my code like this

```
public class ErrorHandlingHttpBinding extends DefaultHttpBinding {

  @Override
  public void doWriteExceptionResponse(Throwable exception, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    if (exception instanceof TimeoutException) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT);
        response.getWriter().write("Continuation timed out...");            
    } else {
      super.doWriteExceptionResponse(exception, response);
    }
  }
}
```

registered as spring bean with `id="errorHandlingHttpBinding"` and referred in the component string as `jetty:http://localhost:21010/?useContinuation=true&continuationTimeout=1&httpBindingRef=errorHandlingHttpBinding`.